# how to get parameters' value from curl in REST web service in java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, httprequest, file-upload

Do anyone know how to get parameters' values from curl command in REST web service using java.I have write a REST web service using jersey framework and java in NetBean IDE.
This is my curl command to uplaod file without metadata:

```
curl -T C:\Users\Folders\a.jpg -H "Content-Type:application/vnd.org.snia.cdmi.dataobject" http://localhost:8080/users/folder/a.jpg
```

This is my HttpPut method for upload

```
@PUT
@Path("/{directory:.+}")
public Response doPut(@PathParam("directory")String data,byte[]contents)
{
..............
}
```

This is my curl command to upload file with metadata

```
curl  --data " { "metadata" : "Username":"name"}" -T C:\Users\Folders\a.jpg -H "Content-Type:application/vnd.org.snia.cdmi.dataobject" http://localhost:8080/users/folder/a.jpg
```

This is my HttpPut method for upload

```
@PUT
@Path("/{direcotry:.+}")
public Response doPut(@PathParam("directory")String data,byte[]contents,String meta)
{
..............
}
```

My question is when i upload file without metadata i can upload successfully. But when i add metadata i can't get the "--data" values from curl command in doPut method. How can I solve it?

Comment: @Path("/{direcotry:.+}") is that a typo ?

Comment: hi PeterMmm, @Path("/{directory:.+}") is the path to upload file.It is working. Now the problem is in second method "String meta", When I write --data in curl to get metadata , i can't get the value

Comment: But how you want to get the value injected if there is still "/{direcotry:.+}". @PathParam("directory") won't find a match.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with curl, but if I'm reading the manpage right, --data and -T are two different ways of setting the POST data for a request. So I don't know what happens if you use both at the same time. I'm not sure what you want the HTTP request to look like.

Comment: hi matrixfrog, yeah , i realized that --data and -T can't use at the same time.But I want to pass the parameter from PUT curl command to give upload file path and some data at the same time.Do you have any idea to suggest thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to submit both a blob of binary data (the jpg) and some metadata (json string) in a single request, I'd recommend a **request that submits a form** (content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). This allows you to include both items in the request body.

Each item in the request is mapped to a method parameter using the [`@FormParam`](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.0/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html) annotation, so you'd have something like this:

```
@PUT
@Path("/{directory:.+}")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public Response doPut(@PathParam("directory") String directory,
                      @FormParam byte[] image,
                      @FormParam String metadata) {
    ...
}
```

For details on how to continue testing this with curl, see the [`--data-urlencode`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode) argument.